# (BATCH) Program shuts down without any error verbose at all

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, bots, event-log

I'm working on a small log clearing application, and was creating a section where the user could deploy a bot to clear Windows event logs automatically given a specific time.

During a test of the bot setup, I got to the part where the program asks the user what types of logs they want cleared, and then the program just randomly quit, without displaying any error messages at all.

Here's the section where the shut down occurs:

```
:bot.noexist.15
if %bot.logtype%=="all" set bot.logtype=all
if %bot.logtype%=="All" set bot.logtype=all
if %bot.logtype%=="Application" set bot.logtype=app
if %bot.logtype%=="application" set bot.logtype=app
if %bot.logtype%=="Security" set bot.logtype=sec
if %bot.logtype%=="security" set bot.logtype=sec
if %bot.logtype%=="System" set bot.logtype=sys
if %bot.logtype%=="system" set bot.logtype=sys
if %bot.logtype%=="application, security" set bot.logtype=app,sec
if %bot.logtype%=="application, system" set bot.logtype=app,sys
pause
if %bot.logtype%=="security, application" set bot.logtype=app,sec
if %bot.logtype%=="security, system" set bot.logtype=sec,sys
if %bot.logtype%=="system, application" set bot.logtype=app,sys
if %bot.logtype%=="system, security" set bot.logtype=sec,sys
pause
echo %bot.logtype%
pause
goto bot.noexist.14
```

I haved narrowed down the location of the problem. It is in between the first two pauses.

Maybe I'm just totally blind, but for the life of me, I cannot see what it wrong here. I don't see any typos, any mis-typed code, nothing.

Edit: because so many are wondering, I DID previously `set bot.logtype="%bot.logtype%"`.

Comment: Maybe "application" and "app", at the same line, are inverted in positions, two times.

Comment: Perhaps it would make it easier to analyse if you were to divulge the value of `bot.logtype` that triggers this problem.

Comment: you are comparing `value` with `"value"` which will never return true.. perhaps wrap the `variable` in double quotes as well.. `if "%bot.logtype%"=="all"`

Comment: Consider to use the `/I` option to do case-insensitive comparisons, like this: `if /I "%bot.logtype%"=="all"`...

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I guess I probably should have mentioned it, but in one of the previous sections, I had a command: `set bot.logtype="%bot.logtype%"`, because for some reason, one of the computers I work with doesn't like it when I use `if "%var%"=="value"`.

Answer (score 0):

### *The actual answer:*

Let's go through the part that is throwing errors step by step - 
*Assume the value of `%bot.logtype%` is `"security, application"`.*

```
if %bot.logtype%=="security, application" set bot.logtype=app,sec
```

This is fine, now `%bot.logtype%` is equal to `app,sec`.

```
if %bot.logtype%=="security, system" set bot.logtype=sec,sys
:: Equivalent to:
:: if app,sec=="security, system" …
:: sec=="security, system" was unexpected at this time.
```

The problem is the commas in the new value of `%bot.logtype%`.

There are a few ways to fix this:

**Method 1**
Add a `goto label` statement -

```
if %bot.logtype%=="security, system" set bot.logtype=sec,sys & goto finish
:: if …

:finish
:: Code here
```

**Method 2**
Surround your new value in `""` again -

```
if %bot.logtype%=="security, application" set bot.logtype="app,sec"
```

**Method 3**
Don't use commas -

```
if %bot.logtype%=="security, application" set bot.logtype=app/sec
```

---

*This fluff is going to stay because it might be relevant to those who find this question in the future.*

**Q1 - Is the value of `%bot.logtype%` never going to be `nul`?**
If `%bot.type%` is based around user-input you will have problems, or if there is ever going to be a case where it is not set when you start comparing it.

You can handle this within your `if` statements by adding extra characters to compare to. The most common is `""` (the reason being **Q2**):

```
if "%emptyVar%"=="" echo emptyVar is empty

:: Can be done with any character(s)
if #%emptyVar%==# echo emptyVar is empty
```

---

**Q2 - Is the contents of `%bot.type%` surrounded by ""?**
When comparing a variable that has a value with spaces in it, it must be surrounded by `""` to prevent errors. If not, then your `if` statement expands like so:

```
set "myStr=string with spaces"    
if %myStr%==value echo.

:: expands to
if string with spaces==value

:: which returns
"with" was not expected at this time
```

You can fix this by encapsulating the variable in `""` when it is being compared:

```
set "myStr=string with spaces"
if "%myStr"=="string with spaces" echo true
:: returns true
```

---

**Q3 - Have you heard of the `IF /I` switch?**

As per the `IF` command line documentation:

> If Command Extensions are enabled IF changes as follows:
>
> ```
> IF [/I] string1 compare-op string2 command
> ```
>
> ...the `/I` switch, if specified, says to do case insensitive string
>   compares.  The `/I` switch can also be used on the `string1==string2` form
>   of `IF`.  These comparisons are generic, in that if both string1 and
>   string2 are both comprised of all numeric digits, then the strings are
>   converted to numbers and a numeric comparison is performed.

By utilising this you could cut your `IF` statements down by half.

So:

```
if %bot.logtype%=="Security" set bot.logtype=sec
if %bot.logtype%=="security" set bot.logtype=sec
```

Becomes:

```
if /i %bot.logtype%=="security" set bot.logtype=sec
```

Comment: Q1: `%bot.logtype%` can never be empty. Yes, it is based on user input, but I have it set so that the program cannot continue on unless the user inputs one of the listed strings, thus all the if statements. Q2: I apologize for not mentioning this earlier, but earlier in the code, I have a command: `set bot.logtype="%bot.logtype%"`. Q3: Thank you for that, this is very useful. I will use this often in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `Choice` command instead to avoid allowing user to type, instead just let them select from a list:

```
@echo off
echo select one:
echo    [1] For Application
echo    [2] For Security
echo    [3] For System
echo    [4] For System and Security
echo    [5] For System and Application
echo    [6] For Security and Application
echo    [7] For Security and System
echo    [8] For All (Application, Security and System)

choice /C 12345678
goto :%errorlevel%
goto :eof
:1
echo Clear Application logs here
goto :eof
:2
echo Clear Security logs here
goto :eof
:3
echo Clear System logs here
goto :eof
:4
echo Clear System and Security logs here
goto :eof
:5
echo Clear System and Application logs here
goto :eof
:6
echo Clear For Security and Application
goto :eof
:7
echo Clear Security and System logs here
goto :eof
:8
echo Clear All logs here
```

Comment: I would use this, but I am making this program for the public. It will be a software for Windows developers, and I am already too far into development of the program to change the entire user input system, and it would be unprofessional to just have one user input method on one section, then a different one on another. However, I will most certainly use this the future, so thanks!